# Why is this Sylius Resource API asking for Templaets?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sylius

I'm trying to create a Sylius Resource.  I've created a Doctrine entity named `App\Entity\Thing`

```
./src/Repository/ThingRepository.php
./src/Entity/Thing.php
```

and, [per Sylius docs](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.4/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/), I added the following to my route configuration

```
app_thing:
   resource: |
       alias: app.thing
   type: sylius.resource_api
```

and the following to my application's configuration

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.thing:
            classes:
                model: App\Entity\Thing
```

According the Sylius docs, I should be apply to fetch a "thing" via the API with a curl call like this

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8000/things/1
```

However, when I try that I get the following error

```
Unable to find template "/show.html.twig" (looked into: /path/to/acme/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views, /path/to/acme/templates, /path/to/acme/templates, /path/to/acme/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form).
```

The error seems to be asking for certain twig templates to be there -- which I don't understand since this is meant to be a JSON Api.  I assume I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or have advice on how I can debug this further?

Here's the output for the `sylius:debug:resource` command.  I'm running Sylius standard edition.

```
$ php bin/console sylius:debug:resource app.thing
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| name               | thing                                                      |
| application        | app                                                        |
| driver             | doctrine/orm                                               |
| classes.model      | App\Entity\Thing                                           |
| classes.controller | Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController |
| classes.factory    | Sylius\Component\Resource\Factory\Factory                  |
| classes.form       | Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Form\Type\DefaultResourceType |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something missing in the documentation.
API Routes need the ^/api prefix.
One solution could be to add a path to your routing config:

```
  app_thing:
    resource: |
      alias: app.thing
      path: /api/things
    type: sylius.resource_api
```

Comment: +1 thank you!  That's useful information.  I was able to get an oAuth error out of the system with the above in place -- so that's progress :)

Comment: Thats somehow typical for any Symfony Documentation. They assume you know everything else :) But you get the hang out of it if work more with it. For the OAuth Error look at: https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.4/cookbook/api/api.html